# PHP - Make reference parameter optional?

Tags: php

Say I've defined a function in PHP, and the last parameter is passed by reference.  Is there any way I can make that optional? How can I tell if it's set?

I've never worked with pass-by-reference in PHP, so there may be a goofy mistake below, but here's an example:

```
$foo;
function bar($var1,&$reference)
{
    if(isset($reference)) do_stuff();
    else return FALSE;
}

bar("variable");//reference is not set
bar("variable",$foo);//reference is set
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Taken from [PHP official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

*NULL* can be used as default value, but it can not be passed from outside

```
<?php

function foo(&$a = NULL) {
    if ($a === NULL) {
        echo "NULL\n";
    } else {
        echo "$a\n";
    }
}

foo(); // "NULL"

foo($uninitialized_var); // "NULL"

$var = "hello world";
foo($var); // "hello world"

foo(5); // Produces an error

foo(NULL); // Produces an error

?>
```

Comment: Look at @Michal Lohniský [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29895514/1008530). He has a good insight about the NULLs.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for those who will see this answer in the future, foo(5) and foo(NULL) are throwing error because ONLY VARIABLES can be passed by reference ( 5 and NULL are not variables )

Comment: One thing to beware of is that the caller could call the function with a variable that has the value `null`. For this reason, if the reference variable is purely used as an output variable, there's no need to check if it is null - doing so could cause unexpected behaviour if the variable contains null before calling the function.

Answer (score 12):

In reaction to [@Martin Perry's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636725/php-make-reference-parameter-optional/16636807#16636807), you can distinguish between

```
foo(); // "NULL"
```

and

```
foo($uninitialized_var); // "NULL"
```

using [func_num_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

Answer (score 10):

You can make argument optional by giving them a default value:

```
function bar($var1, &$reference = null)
{
    if($reference !== null) do_stuff();
    else return FALSE;
}
```

However please note that passing by reference is bad practice in general. If suddenly my value of `$foo` is changed I have to find out why that is only to find out that it is passed by reference. So please only use that when you have a valid use case (and trust me most aren't).

Also note that if `$reference` is supposed to be an object, you probably [don't have to](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) (and shouldn't) pass it by reference.

Also currently your function is returning different types of values. When The reference is passed it returns `null` and otherwise `false`.

Comment: I would upvote if it weren't for "[...] objects are passed by reference by default", which could use further clarification. http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html

Comment: @PleaseStand I am talking about how it is behaving in user land. I could start talking about ref counts etc, but I think that would only confuse OP

Comment: I've edited your post to add a link to the PHP documentation on this, which doesn't mention "ref counts". Feel free to revert the change if you don't think it's clear enough.

Comment: @user1363115 If you really want to understand how it works I suggest you to watch this: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/programming-with-anthony-references.html

Comment: Quote: `However please note that passing by reference is bad practice in general.` Would you say using `preg_match()` is bad practice in general?

Comment: No not at all. As a matter of fact I don't understand where the `preg_match` hate is coming from. I mean sure some things are better solved using e.g. `strpos` and the likes but `preg_match` *is* useful.

Comment: :) don't understand me wrong! I'm not a *hater* in any way! :) I just wanted to point out, that passing by reference isn't bad practice. That's just wrong. Right is, that passing by reference may have side effects which an unexperienced programmer may not expect. but there are of course reasons for passing by reference

Comment: There indeed are (which was the point I tried to make (and likely failed)). But the actual valid use cases are *very* limited (more limited than most people think). You would almost always just want to simply return values where it makes sense. But you are right when you say there are *some* valid use cases.

Comment: Not sure if this still applies, but I like to pass a variable $status by reference when I make API calls. I get returned what the API returns but also get the HTTP status code set by reference

Answer (score 3):

you can set default values

```
$foo;
function bar($var1,&$reference = false)
{
    if($reference != false) do_stuff();
     else return FALSE;
}

bar("variable");//reference is not set
bar("variable",$foo);//reference is set
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing by reference is essential useful for assignments and sometimes you don't need to check if the value is `null`.  This would allow indiscriminate assignment of values to variables including uninitialized ones.

```
function f(&$ref = null) {
    $ref = 1234;
}

f($x);
echo $x; // 1234
f(); // No error
```

Useful in codes like this:

```
if (doSomething($value, $errorMessage) === false) {
    logError($errorMessage);
}

doSomething($value); // Explicitly ignore error message
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
use function bar($var1,&$reference=null)
{
    if(isset($reference)) do_stuff();
    else return FALSE;
}
```

if you pass value to &$reference it will take that value. or else null.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

Declare a default value, which is outside of the regular value range, for example `-1`

```
function bar($var1,&$reference = -1)
{
    if($reference !== -1) do_stuff();
    else return FALSE;
}
```

Do not declare the param and check `func_get_args()` to see if it was passed:

```
function bar($var1)
{
    if(count(func_get_args()) > 1) do_stuff();
    else return FALSE;
}
```

But note, the second approach will trigger a deprecated warning: `Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated;`

Comment: if(func_num_args() > 1) do_stuff();

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet illustrates that a reference is just an alias for a variable name:

```
<?php
function set_variable(&$var, $val)
{
  $var = $val;
}

set_variable($b, 2);
echo $b; // 2
?>
```

This [article](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/05/24/php-variables-passing-by-value-or-reference/) by Larry Ullman explains the basics of passing variable by reference vs passing by value.

What's interesting is that at the end of Larry's article is a link to another [article](http://derickrethans.nl/talks/phparch-php-variables-article.pdf) that goes in depth to explain the underpinnings of references and variables in PHP.

All in all, when making reference parameter optional by giving a default value, PHP 'creates' a new variable which holds the default value in case we do not provide a value for the optional parameter. But, in case we do provide one, we must provide a variable for which the reference parameter is but an alias.