# PHP: Reference-Variable is not needed every time

Tags: php

I have a function with a reference-param

```
function foo($a, &$bar){...}
```

This function can be called by two ways. Directly in the code with

```
foo($a, $bar);
```

or with an variable-call:

```
$function = "foo";
$function();
```

At the second call, I don't know, which function is called and what parameters it needs. So I won't give it parameters at all. (that's fine)

But when I call the function like the second way, I get an PHP-Warning:

```
Missing argument 2 for foo()
```

Because I know, it is right, that I don't it parameters, is it possible to code it, that the code does not give me a warning?

Comment: `function foo($a, &$bar = false){...}` [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Make reference parameter optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636725/php-make-reference-parameter-optional)

Comment: yeah, thats the same. Did not fund that. Tank you both!